# AdColony Aurora Android 3.0 SetCustomID

Tags: java, android, adcolony, rewardedvideoad

I'm attempting to integrate AdColony into an app. I'd like to set a custom ID for each user that gets passed back in the server to server callback I can setup in their dashboard. Right now the custom ID field returns null because it isn't set.

From what I can tell in their new [java docs](https://adcolony-www-common.s3.amazonaws.com/Javadoc/3.0.4/index.html), they seem to have removed the setCustomID call from the AdColony class - or just overlooked it.

Their [old docs for 2.3.6](https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-Android-SDK/wiki/API-Details#setcustomid-string-id-) have a built in method that makes it easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the name has changed to setUserID() and is now located on the AppOptions object. So you can do it like this:

```
    AdColonyAppOptions options = new AdColonyAppOptions();
    options.setUserID("MY USER ID");

    AdColony.configure(this, options, "MY APP ID", "MY ZONE ID");
```